# reference request: a Schaum's outline for calculus on manifolds

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am doing some self-study on calculus on manifolds, and was hoping to find a book like Schaum's Outline for the subject. Does anyone know if manifolds are covered in any of the Schaum's outline texts?

I checked the Schaum's Outlines on Calculus, Advanced Calculus, Differential Geometry, and Tensors. However none of these seem to go over the fundamentals of calculus on manifolds.

I have not checked through the Schaum's outlines on Physics or other topics. Does anyone know if the subject of manifolds is covered in any of the other Schaum's outlines?

Comment: Have you tried googling "Schaum Outline Manifold" -- I got two hits, one for tensor calc, and one for topology, which taken together should give you a good start. (And there's also a pointer to a Springer book that sounds ideal ... something like the 4th hit.)

Comment: @JohnHughes Hey John. Yeah, I tried that. The topology book is only on point-set topology and does not cover manifolds. I looked through the tensor book. There is one chapter on Tensor fields on Manifolds at the very end. The differential geometry book also has one chapter on surfaces. So I can probably make do by knitting together these pieces. I was just curious of there was an outline that covered the whole topic. Thanks for the tips though.

Comment: You could have a look at undergraduate courses on differential geometry, and see if any of those have references to books on calculus on manifolds. Eg my maths department did while I was at university.